# 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'is_authenticated'

Tags: python, django-2.1

I am checking whether the user is authenticated or not in my `views.py`. Django however keeps throwing exception `WSGIRequest object has no attribute 'is_authenticated'`. I read through some of the similar questions on both stackoverflow and github regarding this issue, everyone was pointing towards moving the middleware.I have tried almost every way to restructure my MIDDLEWARE as mentioned in other answers for the same issue but I haven't been able to resolve it. I even read the documentation for [ordering middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/middleware/#process-request) but wasn't able to gather much from this.

views.py

```
@staticmethod
def cmshome(request):
    if request.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('/cms/')
    username = request.session['user']
    profile_object = Profile.objects.all().filter(user__username=username)
    return render(request, 'cms/cmshome.html', {'profile_content': profile_object})
```

Middleware

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you wanted to write:

```
if request.user.is_authenticated:
    return redirect('/cms/')
```